# Automator Folder Action doesn't set the desktop background

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, macos-sierra

I just started playing around with automator, and I am trying to make a folder action that changes my wallpaper whenever I save a picture with a certain name.

The Folder Action/Workflow is set up as follows:
[image]

However, in the `System Preferences` it says that the wallpaper was successfully changed, but it doesn't actually show up as my wallpaper. Am I missing something in the workflow? The action runs without any errors.